# Redirect to https for certain url only for wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https

I'm working on a wordpress site. And just installed SSL. It has been installed correctly but I want to redirect visitors to the https url for certain pages only. I also want to force browser to use http for other pages.

I know this can be done with .htaccess and tried several things as well. But unable to get this as I need. I'm a novice at handling .haccess rewrite rules and can't find the docs that can guide me.

For example, I need to force browser to use https for this two urls:
`http://www.example.com/sells/payment/`
`http://www.example.com/customer/login/`

and for all other urls to just use normal http forcefully. What kind of rules I need to write?

**Update 1**

I also have a rule that redirects non-www url to a www url, and that might be conflicting with these rules. Here is how I redirect all non-www urls to www urls.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The issue I'm facing is, after applying https rules, it is redirected to https://www.www.example.com/sells/payment/ which is a wrong url.

Any idea for fixing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(sells/payment|customer/login)/ - [E=MY_URL:1]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{ENV:MY_URL} 1
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{ENV:MY_URL} !=1
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
```

#### UPDATE:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(sells/payment|customer/login)/ - [E=MY_URL:1]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{ENV:MY_URL} 1
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{ENV:MY_URL} !=1
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work. But after applying your rules it is redirected to https but to a wrong url. This might be because I have rules for redirecting non www urls to www urls. Please see the updated details on the question.  Kindly advise.

Comment: @Krunal Make sure your existing rule of adding `www` comes after my code in you .htaccess.

Comment: Thank you for your update. I checked with that as well. The URL is now redirected to a https://www.www.example.com/sells/payment/ which doesn't exist. Note the two www at the start of URL. Pls advise.

Comment: I have tried with commenting rules that redirects non-www to www urls, and still the issue is same. No idea what is happening. Kindly advise.

Comment: this also doesn't work :( Now it is redirected to http://www.example.com/index.php. Any idea what's going on? The rules don't seem to work here either... http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

Comment: Do NOT test on http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ since it doesn't support env variables in .htacccess, test it directly on your apache web server.

Comment: btw I tested same code again and it worked fine on my Apache.

Comment: `it doesn't work` doesn't give me any info. You need to do soe investigation on your end, look into error.log and access.log and post the relavant sections of those logs in your question. Also it will be good if you can post your latest .htaccess here as well.

Answer (score 1):

This what I've used consistently across my projects where I have similar use-cases as yourself:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT}s ^(443(s)|[0-9]+s)$
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ - [env=askapache:%2]

# redirect urls with index.html to folder
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^/]+/)*index\.html\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*)index\.html$ http%{ENV:askapache}://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# change // to /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(.*)//(.*)\ HTTP/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ http%{ENV:askapache}://%{HTTP_HOST}/%1/%2 [R=301,L]
```

This is an excerpt from a site where I found the solution, so I can't take credit for it:
[Smart HTTP and HTTPS .htaccess Rewrite](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/http-https-rewriterule-redirect.html)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it, but can you handle it the same way you do cononcial URLs?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com/your-page
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/your-page [R=301,L]
```